# Explain 'Exporting model paths from a package.xml section' of 'Using roslaunch to start Gazebo' tutorial on Gazebo-Classic

Tags: gazebo, ros-noetic

I was going through [this](https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_roslaunch) tutorial on Gazebo-classic & wasn't able to understand [this](https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_roslaunch#Exportingmodelpathsfromapackage.xml) section.

I thought the section meant that: by editing the `package.xml` in the shown way (and sourcing the `setup.bash` of the `catkin_ws` containing the `MYROBOT_description` package), the `GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH` env variable will be set automatically instead of having to set it manually.

But when I edited the `package.xml` in the shown way & did `catkin_make` & sourced the `setup.bash`, the `GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH` env variable is still not set.

Can anyone please explain this? Thanks!

P.S:
I'm using ROS Noetic.

Comment: Please edit your question to show how you're actually modifying your package and what commands your actually running. You're likely doing something slightly different than the instructions but if you just copy back the instructions you're trying to follow it's hard to help you determine what you're doing differently.

Comment: Will do that... But in the mean time can you tell if the export tags in the mentioned section of the mentioned tutorial are supposed to set the `GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH` & `GAZEBO_MEDIA_PATH` environment variables automatically? @Tully

Comment: I found some useful info here https://answers.ros.org/question/251862/what-does-the-export-tag-mean/